# Accessing a specific item

Tags: python, tuples

I have the following images:

```
im1 = cv2.imread(root + '/' + '1.jpg')
im1_file = '1.jpg'
img1 = (im1,im1_file)

im2 = cv2.imread(root + '/' + '2.jpg')
im2_file = '2.jpg'
img2 = (im2,im2_file)
```

I then add the images to the `pairs` list, as follows:

```
pair = (img1,img2)
pairs.append(pair)
```

How can I access the file name (i.e. `im_file`) in each pair, `img1` and `img2`?

Comment: What is your expected output here? A list? A list of tuples?

Comment: The main output is a list of tuples. But, what I would like to return is "1.jpg" and "2.jpg", that is the image file names'

Comment: Something like `[(x[0], y[0]) for x, y in pairs]`?

Comment: Python uses `[]` to index collections. Have you tried it?

Comment: Not clear about it really. Should I reply x and y, with img1 and img2, respectively? I get errors here.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the errors, and code with them?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that reproduces the issue. And no, `x` and `y` are loop variables.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you start using numbered variables, use a list.

You can store the file names all at once, and you can then read the files from that list.

```
import os

root = '/'
files = ['1.jpg', '2.jpg']
images = [cv2.imread(os.path.join(root, f) for f in files)]
```

You can access a specific item with `images[0]`, for example.

If you need to join the lists for any reason, you can `zip(files, images)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple tuple indexing to get the filename out (which indeed is the second, or 1-index, element in the tuple)

```
>>> img1[1]
'1.jpg'
```

Or as a collection:

```
>>> for pair in pairs:
...     print(pair[1])
1.jpg
2.jpg
```

However you may want to consider using namedtuples here

```
from collections import namedtuple

ImageInfo = namedtuple("ImageInfo", "data name")

img1 = ImageInfo(im1, im1_file)
img2 = ImageInfo(im2, im2_file)
```

This makes your interface a little nicer to use

```
>>> img1.name
'1.jpg'

>>> for pair in pairs
...     print(pair.name)
1.jpg
2.jpg
```

(in full disclosure, I tend to overengineer my data structures and a namedtuple may be a bit too heavy here depending on the context. Without knowing that, I tend to prefer to overcomplicate. YMMV.)

Comment: separately from your question, and as cricket_007 points out in his answer, you shouldn't be naming things like `x1`, `x2`, `x3` etc in 95% of circumstances. You should prefer a list `xs = [x1, x2, x3]`